# How can I put multiple sidebars in different areas of my template in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I have created a custom theme and a very basic layout for my **WordPress (4.7)** application which looks like this:

[image]

In my `functions.php` file I have registered a few `sidebars`.

```
function flowershouse_widgets_init(){
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Main content left', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'content-main-left',
            'description' => __('Add widgets to appear in left column of main content area', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));

        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Main content right', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'content-main-right',
            'description' => __('Add widgets to appear in right column of main content area', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));

        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Sidebar', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'sidebar-1',
            'description' => __('Add widgets here to appear in sidebar', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</section>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));

        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Footer Left', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'footer-left',
            'description' => __('Add widgets to appear in left footer', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));

        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Footer Middle', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'footer-middle',
            'description' => __('Add widgets here to appear in middle footer column', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));

        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => __('Footer Right', 'flowershouse'),
            'id' => 'footer_right',
            'description' => __('Add widgets here to appear in Right footer column', 'flowershouse'),
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_widget' => '<h2>'
        ));
    }

    add_action('widgets_init', 'flowershouse_widgets_init');
```

All registered sidebars are available under `Appearance > Widgets` page. In `sidebar.php` file I have this:

```
if (is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
}
if (is_active_sidebar('content-main-left')){
    dynamic_sidebar('content-main-left');
}
```

I put Search widget under `sidebar-1` and put `Meta` under `content-main-left` sidebar. But when the page renders both the widgets are being shown under the same sidebar. This is how my `index.php` looks like:

```html
...
    <div class="row margin-t20">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="box box-gray padd-10-all">
                    Left column with 9 column
                    <div class="row margin-t10">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
<!-- Here I want 'content-main-left' sidebar widgets to render -->
                                <?php get_sidebar('content-main-left'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mobile-v-space">
                            <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
                                Right content<br />(inside 9-column left column)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 mobile-v-space">
                <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
<!-- Here I want 'sidebar-1' sidebar widgets to render -->
                    <?php get_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    ...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130830/discussion-on-question-by-subrata-sarkar-how-can-i-put-multiple-sidebars-in-diff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**
Its include whole file at once.that why it include all sidebar in same block.

**Case 1 : Direct call a sidebar (Working Properly)**

```
   <div class="row margin-t20">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box box-gray padd-10-all">
                Left column with 9 column
                <div class="row margin-t10">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
                            <?php if (is_active_sidebar('content-main-left')){dynamic_sidebar('content-main-left');} ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mobile-v-space">
                        <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
                            Right content<br />(inside 9-column left column)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Right Side bar -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 mobile-v-space">
            <div class="box box-white padd-10-all">
                <?php if (is_active_sidebar('fw_sidebar')){dynamic_sidebar('fw_sidebar');} ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

**Case 2 : Create file and call**

create two files and add code of sidebar.i.e. I have a two sidebar called sidebar-1 and sidebar-2.Now I create a file for that with slug name.

**file name : sidebar-1.php**

```
if (is_active_sidebar( 'fw_sidebar' )) {
      dynamic_sidebar( 'fw_sidebar' );
  }
```

**file name : sidebar-2.php**

```
if (is_active_sidebar('content-main-left')){
dynamic_sidebar('content-main-left');
}
```

while call this sidebar just call function get_sidebar(slugname). for example,

```
 <?php get_sidebar(1); ?>
 <?php get_sidebar(2); ?>
```

Comment: @SubrataSarkar fixed sent

Comment: +1 :) I would rather prefer to use `Case-1` as it is more readable easy to understand. I added three sidebars at different areas and they work perfect ! "Problem Its include whole file at once.that why it include all sidebar in same block" - this is the most valuable info. Thank you so much!

Comment: This helped me tremendously. Thank you!